# why is this speckled effect happing on my glass texture

Tags: texturing

Why is this happening to my glass?

Please go to this link to view all the images and node set up my rp won't let me post them on here
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U7fvwVdh7irDTfBEgvM8LlasSaXdl-reTB9kMsUUl_A/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the blend file
[image]

Comment: How is your material set up? What are your render settings? Need more information about your scene, or you can upload a *simplfied, with textures packed* example file demonstrating the issue to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add information describing how you set up the material for the glass, add images of your nodes and other information you might consider relevant for others to help you out.